# How to run command after the completion is inserted into the text editor (VS Code Extension)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my VS Code Extension I would like the opening and closing parentheses to be inserted automatically after a function is selected from the list provided by the completion item provider.

After the parentheses are added, I would like the extension to trigger the signature help provider (note that VS Code triggers the signature help provider when you manually type the opening parenthesis `(`.

Here's a snippet of what I've added inside the `provideCompletionItems` method:

```js
myFunctions.forEach((func) => {
    const completion = new CompletionItem(func, CompletionItemKind.Function);
    completion.detail = func.signature;
    completion.documentation = func.description;
    completion.insertText = func + '(';
    ...
});
```

I am aware that I can execute a command after inserting a completion by adding something like

```js
completion.command = ...
```

The VS Code Extension API has [`vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) as a built-in command to execute the Signature Help Provider. Thus, I would run this command like this:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider', document.uri, position)
```

However, I don't know how to run this command as part of the `command` variable, meaning that I can't do

```js
completion.command = vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider', document.uri, position)
```

because the `command` variable accepts only the type `Command`.

So, how would I be able to run a command after the completion is inserted into the editor?

---

SOLUTION:

Based on the answers below, I realized I was using the wrong command to trigger the parameter hints widget. Instead, I used the `editor.action.triggerParameterHints` command:

```js
completion.command = { command: 'editor.action.triggerParameterHints', title: '' };
```

Comment: if you want to modify the document after insertion use `additionalTextEdits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `editor.action.triggerParameterHints` command instead. If you have registered your own SignatureHelpProvider that should trigger it to run. If you haven't registered your own, that should trigger the default provider.

`completion.command = "editor.action.triggerParameterHints";`

---

You can also invoke a command, if you have more work to do there, via this in your `CompletionItem`:

```js
newCommand.command = "<your extension name>.selectDigitInCompletion";
newCommand.title = "Select the digit 'n' in completionItem";
newCommand.arguments = [key, replaceRange, position];  // whatever args you want to pass to the command
completion.command = newCommand;
```

And then that command is registered somewhere - it doesn't have to be in the `package.json`:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('<your extension name>.selectDigitInCompletion', async (completionText, completionRange, position) => {

// ...

// access your passed-in args `completionText`,`completionRange` and `position` here
// await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider', document.uri, position)

...

}
```

Comment: I see. I now understand how to invoke a command with arguments, such as the case of the `vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider` command. This is what I did: `completion.command = { command: 'vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider', title: '', arguments: [document.uri, position] };`. However, even though I am pretty sure I am doing things correctly this time, the signature help widget is not being displayed after a completion is inserted. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Or, maybe I am interpreting the documentation wrongly. Executing the signature help provider may not mean that the parameter hints widget will be displayed. Does there exist a command to do this?

Comment: Try the `editor.action.triggerParameterHints` command instead.  If you have registered your own `SignatureHelpProvider` that should trigger it to run.  If you haven't registered your own, that should trigger the default provider.

Comment: The `editor.action.triggerParameterHints` command worked. I will include this in the description of the question. Thank you.

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.  I think we thought you were looking how to run a command and you wanted to pass arguments to it.

Comment: I actually wanted to know how to run a command, as well as display the parameter hints. I apologize if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

assign an instance of the `Command` object

```
completion.command = { command: 'vscode.executeSignatureHelpProvider', title: 'Signature' };
```